# Print Entire Column Based on Header Match

Tags: regex, unix, awk, sed, grep

I am trying to match a header in  CSV file I am working with, followed by printing the entire column.

**some.file:**

```
col_1,col_2,col_3,col_4,col_5
2333,4345,365678,54356,34443
```

**Code:**

```
awk -F, 'NR==1{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){if($i=="col_3")x=i;}} NR>1{if($x=="1")print;}' some.file
```

When I run this however, I get a blank return...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this `awk`:

```
awk -F',' -v search="col_3" 'NR==1{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){ if ($i == search) c=i } } c{print $c}' file
```

Output:

```
col_3
365678
```

You can pass required column name to `awk` by using `search` variable.

From your example:

```
awk -F, 'NR==1{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){if($i=="col_3")x=i;}} x!=0{print $x}' file
```